# How to extract the shipping prices without simulating clicks using Python?

Tags: python, json, selenium-webdriver, dom

This page [here](https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/1005002384747098.html) and others like it have a bunch of item properties such as color, number of hard drive space, etc. that all may or may not affect the price of the product. I have extracted all of this information already without any problems by going to my console and entering "window.runParams.data" and accessing the Sku module.

Unfortunately, however, I have not been able to find such hard-set values for shipping costs in the shipping module. Are they obtained dynamically behind the scenes somehow? If so, can I use Python to get them with a request of some type through which I can feed their servers my country data and obtain costs or, better yet, just extract it from the already loaded page so that I don't need to simulate clicks with Selenium or something of the sort to get the shipping prices?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check the [network activity](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/), you'll see that the shipping prices are retrieved from an api. So simply reproduce the api call to get the prices:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36',
    'referer': 'https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/1005002384747098.html',
}

params = (
    ('productId', '1005002384747098'),
    ('count', '1'),
    ('country', 'PT'),
    ('tradeCurrency', 'USD'),
    ('ext', '{"disCurrency":"USD","p1":"7.78","p2":"25.59","p3":"USD","p4":"990000","p5":"0","p6":"0.210000"}'),
)

response = requests.get('https://pt.aliexpress.com/aeglodetailweb/api/logistics/freight', headers=headers, params=params).json()

df = pd.json_normalize(response['body']['freightResult'])
```

output:

|  | commitDay | company | currency | deliveryDate | deliveryDateCopy | deliveryDateFormat | discount | displayType | fullMailLine | hbaService | id | name | sendGoodsCountry | sendGoodsCountryFullName | serviceName | time | tracking | bizShowMind.layout | freightAmount.currency | freightAmount.formatedAmount | freightAmount.value | freightLayout.displayType | freightLayout.openShippingPanel | standardFreightAmount.currency | standardFreightAmount.formatedAmount | standardFreightAmount.value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 75 | AliExpress Standard Shipping | USD | 2021-09-26 | Estimated Delivery on {0} | Sep 26 | 0 | deliveryDate | False | False | 0 | FreightItemModule | CN | China | CAINIAO_STANDARD | 22-30 | True | [] | USD | US $3.40 | 3.4 | deliveryDate | true | USD | US $3.40 | 3.4 |
| 1 | 75 | Cainiao Heavy Parcel Line | USD | 2021-09-26 | Estimated Delivery on {0} | Sep 26 | 10 | deliveryDate | False | False | 0 | FreightItemModule | CN | China | CAINIAO_STANDARD_HEAVY | 22-30 | True | [] | USD | US $32.20 | 32.2 | deliveryDate | true | USD | US $32.20 | 32.2 |
| 2 | 75 | DHL | USD | 2021-09-18 | Estimated Delivery on {0} | Sep 18 | 40 | deliveryDate | False | False | 0 | FreightItemModule | CN | China | DHL | 14-22 | True | [] | USD | US $67.91 | 67.91 | deliveryDate | true | USD | US $67.91 | 67.91 |

Comment: Awesome!!!!! Thank you so much man!! This is amazing

Comment: Why doesn't it work on Postman?

Comment: @ArifReza please open a different question for this